# LINQ. Grouping by days. How to do this easily?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, date, grouping

I can't seem to find any good reference on this. I have a lot of data in SQL with dates. So I wanted to make a line chart to show this data over time. If I want to show it over a period of days then I need to group by days.. But the LOGDATE is the full date.. not the DAY..

So I have this below, but LINQ doesn't know what 'DayOfYear' property is...

```
 var q = from x in dc.ApplicationLogs
                let dt = x.LogDate
                group x by new { dayofyear = dt.Value.DayOfYear } into g
                select new
                {
                    iCount = g.Count(),
                    strDate = g.Key
                };
```

Comment: linq2ent.. .seems like some date function are restrcited which is why this is so hard i guess

Comment: I can use LogDate.Value.Day but NOT LogDate.Value.ShortDateTime()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EF core you can use `DateTime.Date` to get the date portion of a `DateTime` value.

In EF6 you can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> to return the given date with the time portion cleared

```
var q = from x in dc.ApplicationLogs
        let dt = x.LogDate.Date
        // EF6:let dt = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LogDate)
        group x by dt into g
        select new
        {
            iCount = g.Count(),
            strDate = g.Key
        };
```

Comment: Cheers. Took me a while on Google searching for this -> exactly what I needed.

Comment: EF6 version returns nullable type instead, so be aware to do some cast or filters after query if you need it

Answer (score 3):

You want `.Date` to get the date part of a `DateTime` not `DayOfyear` unless you are deliberately trying to put the same day of the year from each year into the group.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using:

```
    let dt = x.LogDate
    group x by new { dayofyear = dt.Value.DayOfYear } into g
```

instead of just:

```
    group x by x.LogDate.Value.DayOfYear into g
```

I'm not sure about this, but it's possible using an anonymous object like that in your `group by` clause is messing up L2S.

Comment: dayofyear is not supported by Line2Ent. :(

Comment: This works.. but only for data within ONE month :(

 var q = from x in dc.ApplicationLogs
                    group x by new { x.LogDate.Value.Day } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        DayDate = g.Key.Day,
                        iCount = g.Count()
                    };

Comment: How about just fetching all the data into a `List<LogDate>` and then doing the grouping with plain old LINQ-to-Objects?

Comment: not sure how to do that.. I mean how to mix a linq2ent query with linqtoobjects

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
let d = new DateTime(n.time.Year, n.time.Month, n.time.Day) group n by d into grp select grp
```

Comment: Calling `new DateTime(...)` in a LINQ to Entities query will fail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti