# Convert list of of objects to list of tuple without iterating

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, tuples

I'm trying to add an extra parameter to a list of ef objects to track processing, but I keep running into having to initialize each list item explicitly. What's the correct linq way to do this? Aside from terseness, is there any advantage to a linq syntax in this case?

```
List<app_subjects> subjectList = AppMySQLQueries.GetAllSubjects();
List<Tuple<app_subjects, bool>> subjectCollection = new List<Tuple<app_subjects, bool>>(subjectList.Count);

foreach (app_subjects subject in subjectList)
{
     subjectCollection.Add(Tuple.Create(subject, false));
}
```

I have searched the site without success.

Comment: `LINQ` can do this but it looks very similar to a traditional `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: LINQ would also do the iteration, *(internally)*

Comment: @Habib The difference is that with LINQ you may be able to defer the execution of the work.

Comment: @Servy, true but not when he calls to list which, given the sample code, might be necessary.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Hence the "may" in my statement.

Comment: @Servy yeah, I gave some explanation of the deferred execution in my answer.

Comment: List<Tuple<T1, T2>> seriously? How about Dictionary<T1, T2>?

Comment: @Dantix you often have no control over what kind of collections you use in a mature code base.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just want to use a projection here ( `Select` ) which applies the transformation in your lambda expression to each element in the source collection.

```
List<Tuple<app_subjects, bool>> tuples = subjectList.Select(x => new Tuple<app_subjects, bool>(x, false)).ToList();
```

The `ToList()` call is not entirely necessary, if you removed it then the method will return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<app_subjects, bool>>`. If you're just going to iterate the collection of tuples afterwards the `ToList` call should be removed as it forces execution (enumerates the `IEnumerable`) and then your next operation (the foreach) would do the same, making the code perform worse.

Comment: Sorry, the lambda "x.subject" is invalid because it resolves to a method in the ef class, not the class itself.

Comment: @AldoSalzberg yeah, I've put in an edit. I thought `app_subject` was a property of the objects in the `subjectList` collection. Since it's actually just a `List<app_subject` it should be `x` instead of `x.subject`.

Comment: Use ConvertAll instead.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. what is the advantage of using ConvertAll?

Comment: @evan It's faster (only enumerates once)

Comment: @It'sNotALie. well that's just wrong... If you don't call `ToList` it enumerates 0 times. And if you call `ToList` then it enumerates once so it actually performs worse in the one case and the same in the other...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Oh yeah, I forgot about deffered execution. Fair enough.

Comment: I got this error: 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities'

Comment: @QMaster the tags for this question are misleading. The OP is actually using LINQ to Objects. This part of his code uses EF `ist<app_subjects> subjectList = AppMySQLQueries.GetAllSubjects();` but the actual query is not being run by LINQ to Entities, it's LINQ to Objects. When you try it in that context it doesn't work because the LINQ provider translates your query into a SQL query and there are no Tuples in SQL.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal thanks, You right and i found solution for that. please read Yuck answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
subjectList.Select(s => Tuple.Create(s, false)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

With **C# 10.0 (.NET 6.0)** this is even easier and cleaner. Along with named tuples we can also declare a tuple by simply putting the values in round brackets.

```
List<(string NamedProperty1, int NamedProperty2)> _tuples = new();
_tuples = _objectList.Select(o => (o.SomeProperty1, o.SomeProperty2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
List<Tuple<app_subjects, bool>> subjectCollection = subjectList.CovertAll( subject => new Tuple<app_subjects, bool>(){
subject,
false
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, it has to be Tuple.Create(...), not new Tuple.