# How return a Tuple from a SQL Server 2012 database Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have 2 columns `GetProviders` and `GetAwaitingPatients` in a single table in a SQL Server 2012 database.

- `GetProviders` has it is elements stored as a `Tuple<long, string>` array
- `GetAwaitingPatients` has its elements stored as `Tuple<long, long, string>` array

I am trying to simply read and return the data from each of these columns in this single table using C# and Linq with this two methods.

```
public Tuple<long, string>[] GetProviders(Guid sessionId)
{
    var objproviders = (from objProvider in db.Licenses
                        where objProvider.GUID == Convert.ToString(sessionId)
                        select objProvider.GetProviders).ToList();

    return objproviders;
}
```

I am getting an error

> can't convert expression type  "system.Collection.generic.List" to return type "System.Tuple [ ]

Example of data in this column:

```
   10556, Memorial
   21456, Dallas
   38678, Chicago
```

Here is the second method:

```
 public Tuple<long, long, string>[] GetAwaitingPatients(Guid sessionId)
 {
     var objGetAwaiting = (from objGetAwaitingPatient in db.Licenses
                           where objGetAwaitingPatient.GUID == Convert.ToString(sessionId)
                           select objGetAwaitingPatient.GetAwaitingPatients).ToList();

     return objGetAwaiting;
}
```

I am getting an error

> can't convert expression type "system.Collection.generic.List" to return type "System.Tuple [ ]

Example of data in this column:

```
   10,10556, Steven
   35,21456, Sandy
   77,21456, John
```

How do I return the correct return type and also do it correctly? I tried using list to return as a list but that does not seem to work for me. Any insights or help is well appreciated.

Comment: you can change your return types or build up the Tuples that you seem to be expecting.  The error message is pretty straightforward, why are you expecting Tuples when you call `ToList()`?

Comment: i tried to see if i could convert it to List but that did not work

Comment: You can try this link, look like similar to your question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664186/convert-list-of-ef-objects-to-tuple-without-iterating    List<Tuple<string, bool>> tuples = subjectList.Select(x => new Tuple<string, bool>(x, false)).ToList();

Comment: The **real solution** would be to store the data in a *real, relational fashion* - don't store multiple values into a single table cell! If you have five tuple - those should be **five rows** in a separate table!

Comment: Why is the property GetAwaitingPatients named like a method? I was about to post an answer that you are simply not calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply calling the `ToArray()` extension method instead of `ToList()`.
That should do the trick.