# LINQ to Entities parameter constructor

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

I've looked around for multiple solutions, but non seemed to work. I aim using a LINQ query to get data and populate an object, however; when I try to assign result to the a ReponseObj I get

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

The constructor for ObjVO is parameterless.

```
 public static ApiResponseObject<ObjVO> GetObjVO(int ID)
        {           
    ApiResponseObject<ObjVO> response = new ApiResponseObject<ObjVO>();
        Context ctx = new Context();
                        var myQuery = from cb in ctx.tblBlock
                                       join eve in ctx.tblEvent on cb.eventID equals eve.eventID
                                       where cb.BlockID == ID
                        select new ObjVO
                        {
                            Id = cb.BlockID,
                            Name = cb.BlockHeadline,
                            TotalTYProjectedSales = cb.totalTYProjectedSale.Value,
                            StoreTYProjectedSales = cb.storeTYProjectedSale.Value,
                            SiteTYProjectedSales = cb.storeTYProjectedSale.Value,
                            ModifiedBy = cb.LAST_UPD_USER_ID,
                            LastModifiedDate = cb.LAST_UPD_TS,
                            StoreUnitsOnHand = cb.storeUnitsOnHand.Value,
                            AssignedCutsCount = 0,
                            BlockHeadline = cb.contentBlockHeadline,
                            BelongsToLockedAd = false,
                            ProductLevel = 1,
                            SiteAvailability = false,
                        };

                        response.responseData = myQuery.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your constructor is really parameterless - no optional parameters for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because EF cannot translate your query into a SQL statement.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti) for reference.

Comment: var a = ctx.tblBlocks.Where(x => x.BlockID == ID).Select(x => new ObjVO());

I don't get an error, but this doesn't seem to be putting my data into the Obj fields.