# Cannot serialise entites to viewmodel type via constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a problem `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`, and am not sure how to resolve this,  I can potentially remove the constructor and initialise these manually however as the code is already there then I was wondering if anything could be done.

```
var entries = Db.Devices.Select(device => new DeviceDetailsModel(device)).ToList();
devices.AddRange(entries);
```

and here is the constructor to the class

```
 public DeviceDetailsModel(Device device)
    {
        DeviceID = device.DeviceID;
        IPAddress = device.IPAddress;
        Alias = device.Alias;
        DeviceName = device.DeviceName;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)

Comment: Basically, the Select is performed as part of a query to your database, and Linq has no idea how to translate your constructor to (presumably) SQL. If you don't care about the amount of columns returned from the database, materialise your result first, then do the transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using Linq to Entities not just LINQ to objects. That`s the difference. Linq to Entities translates your Linq query into SQL query and it has no idea how to translate your constructor. Use initializer instead - Linq to Entity can handle that:

```
  var entries = Db.Devices.Select(x => new DeviceDetailsModel
{
    DeviceID = x.DeviceID;
    IPAddress = x.IPAddress;
    Alias = x.Alias;
    DeviceName = x.DeviceName;
}).ToList();
```