# LINQ join, group by, sum

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, sum

I'm creating a safety tracking HR app, and I'm trying to use LINQ to return the lost hours for each month per safety incident type.  The relevant entity/table columns are:

```
[safety_incident]:
    [incident_id]
    [incident_date]
    [incident_type]
    [facility_id]

[safety_hours]:
    [safety_hours_id]
    [incident_id]
    [safety_hours_date]
    [lost_hours]
```

The relationship between safety_incident and safety_hours is 0..n, with safety_hours noting hours lost for an incident on specific dates.  I'm trying to return a record/object for each combination of incident type and month, over a year (not necessarily all in the same calendar year), where the lost hours is greater than 0.  Without the one-year boundaries or limits on facility, I get what I need from SQL with this:

```
SELECT (datepart(year,safety_hours_date) * 100 + datepart(month,safety_hours_date)),
    inc.incident_type, sum(sh.lost_hours)
FROM [hr].[safety_hours] sh
INNER JOIN [hr].safety_incident inc ON sh.incident_id = inc.incident_id
GROUP BY (datepart(year,safety_hours_date) * 100 + datepart(month,safety_hours_date)),
    inc.incident_type
HAVING sum(sh.lost_hours) > 0
ORDER BY (datepart(year,safety_hours_date) * 100 + datepart(month,safety_hours_date)),
    inc.incident_type
```

The closest I can get to an accepted LINQ query is this:

```
var monthInjuryHours =
                from sh in _context.safety_hours
                where sh.safety_hours_date >= firstMonth && sh.safety_hours_date < monthAfterLast && sh.lost_hours > 0
                join inc in _context.safety_incident on sh.incident_id equals (inc.incident_id) into most
                from m in most
                where (facID == 0 || m.facility_id == facID)
                group m by new
                {
                    m.incident_type,
                    month = new DateTime(sh.safety_hours_date.Year, sh.safety_hours_date.Month, 1)
                } into g
                select new
                {
                    injury = g.Key.incident_type,
                    month = g.Key.month,
                    hours = g.Sum(h => h.lost_hours)    // ERROR, can't access lost_hours
                };
```

Unfortunately, I can't specify lost_hours in the "hours" line, or any properties of safety_hours, only those of safety_incident come up after "h.".  Very grateful for any help, thanks...

EDIT: I was able to rearrange the query to switch the order of the two tables and got something that ran:

```
    var monthInjuryHours =
        from inc in _context.safety_incident
        where (facID == 0 || inc.facility_id == facID) && inc.incident_date < monthAfterLast
        join sh in _context.safety_hours on inc.incident_id equals (sh.incident_id) into most
        from m in most
        where m.safety_hours_date >= firstMonth && m.safety_hours_date < monthAfterLast
            && m.lost_hours > 0
        group m by new
        {
            // Note new aliases
            inc.incident_type,
            month = new DateTime(m.safety_hours_date.Year, m.safety_hours_date.Month, 1)
        } into g
        select new
        {
            injury = g.Key.incident_type,
            month = g.Key.month,
            hours = g.Sum(h => h.lost_hours)
        };
```

But when I tried iterating through it with a foreach, a NotSupportedException pointing to the "in" keyword told me "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."  I swear I've had other queries that returned collections of anonymous types but whatever...

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal example of this? Maybe splitting things out would help you to start with and with the fluent api instead of query syntax you can break things down really easily.

Comment: Not sure how I can minimize my problem further.  I have two tables, each with a column by which I must group, with a sum for each group coming from one of the tables.  I was hoping to use pure LINQ syntax, but I may need a clever hybrid or multiple statements after all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now, the answer is "F(orget) LINQ".  Thanks to [Yuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719034/yuck)'s inspiring answer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti), a ToList() after the Where() allowed this syntax to get exactly the results I was after:

```
var monthInjuryHours = _context.safety_incident.Join(_context.safety_hours,
    inc => inc.incident_id, sh => sh.incident_id, (inc, sh) => new { Inc = inc, Hours = sh })
    .Where(j => j.Hours.lost_hours > 0 && (facID == 0 || j.Inc.facility_id == facID)
                && j.Inc.incident_date < monthAfterLast
                && j.Hours.safety_hours_date >= firstMonth
                && j.Hours.safety_hours_date < monthAfterLast).ToList()    //Fixes things
    .GroupBy(x => new { Month = new DateTime(x.Hours.safety_hours_date.Year,
                           x.Hours.safety_hours_date.Month, 1), x.Inc.incident_type })
    .Select(g => new { g.Key.Month, g.Key.incident_type,
                       LostHours = g.Sum(x => x.Hours.lost_hours) })
    .OrderBy(h => h.Month).ThenBy(h => h.incident_type);
```

I know this wasn't the prettiest or simplest example, but I hope it helps someone.