# Can I pass in a parameter into a .Select in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.  The constructor of `ExtendedA` takes a parameter and this populates the fields in the `A` class.

```
public class A {
        public string English { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedA : A {
        public string English2 { get; set; }
        public ExtendedA(A a) {
           English = a.English;
}
```

I have a database query like this:

```
var abc = db.As
      .Select(x => new ExtendedA(a)
            {
                English2 = "test"
            }).ToList();
```

What I would like to do is to use this constructor in the `.Select` of a LINQ query.

When I try this I get the message: The name a does not exist in the current context.

Can someone give me advice as to if what I am trying to do is possible.

Comment: Do you mean to use the variable `x`? - Like this: `new ExtendedA(x)`

Comment: Where you create and initiate parameter (a)?

Comment: `x` is your `A`, so just try: `x => new ExtendedA(x) { ... }`

Comment: What do you want the value of `abc` to be?

Comment: Is this about Linq to entities (SQL) or some in-memory linq?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367649/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)